# OneToMany return just specific rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have class with attribute

```
@Entity
public class Energy() {
   @Id
   private long id;

   private Date date;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private List<Value> values;
}
```

and Value class have

```
private String obis;
private long value;
```

What is the fastest way to return just elements of list values where obis contains specific value?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't filter on `values` directly? It is `LAZY` so if you select `Energy` you have at least 2 SQL queries compared to 1 if you filter on `values`.

Comment: You were right. Thank you. I was so tired to write simple query. What I needed is this `SELECT c FROM Energy c JOIN FETCH c.values as p where p.Obis = :obis` .

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation you choose, for example with Criteria Api:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Energy> cq = cb.createQuery(Energy.class);

Root<Energy> root = cq.from(Energy.class);
Join<Energy,Value> join = root.join(Energy_.values);
//If you dont use metamodel change by root.join("values")

cq.select(root);
cq.where(cb.equal(join.get(Value_.value),VALUE));
//If you dont use metamodel change by join.get("value")

List<Energy> result = entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your code works great but filtering by query is much faster.